# Font is not applied if name of font start with number or number available in font

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

Font is not applied if any number in font name .

EG:- font-family:"3 grammes 5"

Other Eg:- "grammes 5" ,"3 5 grammes" ,"3 grammes 5"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed in github please use latest version of webfontloader.js

Please add image code in minified js file and if you want actual code go to github.

Image:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydS3a.png

https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader/commit/01f246b9e589e3ae78c2194388b181bb80c853f9